# Spring defaultrollback after class

Tags: spring, hibernate, integration-testing, testng

I have an Integration test using TestNG for a DAO class manager by Spring/Hibernate. As shown below. I was trying to have one test insert the data and then other test just to test the fetch method. So I have used dependsOn provided by TestNG. But now the problem is once my first test ends it roll backs the transaction as I have given defaultRollBack = true in TransactionConfiguration annotation. so my second test fails. Is there any way to stop it and rollback after all the tests in class are done?

```
import static org.testng.Assert.*;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.Rollback;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests;
import org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionConfiguration;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.worksheet.State;


@ContextConfiguration("classpath*:spring-context-test.xml")
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback = true)
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public class StateDAOTest extends AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests{

    @Autowired
    private StateDAO stateDAO;

    @Test
    public void saveUnknownState(){
        State state = new State("Unknown", "UKN");
        stateDAO.saveState(state);
        assertTrue(state.getId() > 0);
    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods = {"saveUnknownState"})
    public void fetchUnknownState(){
        State state = stateDAO.getStateByAbbreviation("UKN");
        assertNotNull(state);
    }
}
```